# How is data with nvarchar[n] type stored?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I create a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Car]
(
    [Car_ID] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Car_CODE] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Car_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
)
```

Does `Car_Name` have a maximum of 50 characters?

Say I give an input like this

```
"Teslaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

(60 chars), will it be stored as

```
"Teslaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

(50 chars) ? Can someone help me with this? Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to insert or update a value greater than the column length by a query or Entity Framework, you'll get an error:

> String or binary data would be truncated

If you use a stored procedure, the truncation will be done automatically and no error will occur.

Comment: Thank you sir. Is there any situation that the above can happen? I'm testing a .net project and every inputs that passes the maximum limit char is stored like the above.

Comment: If you use the Stored Procedures, the truncate will be done automatically and no error will occur

Comment: I didn't mean to use Stored Procedures for check input length,validation should definitely be done at the application level.If we used Stored Procedures to insert data and mistakenly send a value greater than the it's parameter length, there would be no error and the truncation would be used automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The information is not inserted, it gives you an error

`String or binary data would be truncated`

Comment: Thank you sir. Is there any situation that the above can happen? I'm testing a .net project and every inputs that passes the maximum limit char is stored like the above.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see your post raises two questions and therefore two answers.

**1. How is `nvarchar` stored?**

Data type `nvarchar` will store 2 bytes per character whereas `varchar` only 1 byte.

**2. Will my `nvarchar` accept more chars than the maximum permitted?**

No. The `INSERT` statement will fail and you'll be getting an error since it accepts only <= 50 chars.

Comment: Thank you sir. Is there any situation that the above can happen? I'm testing a .net project and every inputs that passes the maximum limit char is stored like the above.